# Сохранение выбранного варианта ответа на странице теста перед переходом к следующему

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Вопросы выводятся по одному с помощью пагинации. Каким образом можно привязать к сессии выбранные варианты ответов и перед сохранением их передать в бд?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Тестирование по курсу {{ $course->course_name }}</h2>
        <div id="timer" value="{{ $time }}"></div>
        <hr/>
        @include('pages.courses.exam-form')
    </div>
</div>
```

pages.courses.exam-form:

```
<div class="container">
<section>
    {!! Form::open(['class' => 'form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'exam.result.store', 'id' => 'examForm']) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('user', Auth::user()->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('exam', $exam->id) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('course', $course->id) !!}
    <div class="question-line" style="display: inline;clear: both;">
    @foreach($questions as $question)
        @if(count($question->answers()->get()))
              <h2>{{ $question->question }}</h2>
                @foreach($question->answers()->get() as $answer)
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            {!! Form::checkbox('answer-'.$answer->id, $answer->id) !!} {{ $answer->answer }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
            @if($question->free)
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ $question->question }}
                    {!! Form::text('free-answer-'.$question->answerFree()->first()->id, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
            @endif
    @endforeach
    </div>
    <hr/>
    @include('pages.pagination.default', ['paginator' => $questions])
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="float: left; margin-top: 20px;">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::route('pages.courses.show', $course->slug) }}">Отмена</a>
        {!! Form::submit('Завершить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'end-test']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</section>
</div>
```

Controller:

Вход в Тестирование из Курса:

```
public function courseExam($id)
{
    try {
        $exam = Exam::findOrFail($id);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        \Session::flash('my-errors', ['error' => 'Тестирование которое вы ищите не найдено']);
        return \Redirect::route('pages.courses.index');
    }
    $course = Course::whereRaw('enter_id = '.$id.' or finish_id = '.$id)->firstOrFail();
    $questions = $exam->questions()->paginate(1);
    $user = \Auth::getUser();
    $futile = Futile::whereRaw('user_id = '.$user->id.' and exam_id = '.$exam->id)->first();
    if (!count($futile)) {
        $futile = new Futile();
        $futile->try_count = 0;
        $futile->try_max = 3;
        $futile->save();
        $exam->futile()->save($futile);
        $user->futile()->save($futile);
    } elseif ($futile->try_count == $futile->try_max) {
        \Session::flash('my-messages', ['result' => 'Вы превысили допустимое количество попыток']);
        return \Redirect::route('pages.courses.show', $course->slug);
    }
    $futile->try_started = 1;
    $limit = $exam->limit()->first();
    if (count($limit)) {
        $futile->try_end_time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', time() + $limit->limits_time*60);
        $futile->try_max = $limit->limits_try;
    } else {
        $futile->try_end_time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', time() + 30*60);
    }
    $futile->save();
    $time = strtotime($futile->try_end_time) - time();
    return view('pages.courses.course-exam', compact('questions', 'course', 'exam', 'time'));
}
```

Сохраняем результат Тестирования:

```
public function storeExam(Request $request)
{
    $result = new Result;
    /** @var $waste_time - Затраченное на тест время */
    $waste_time = time() - strtotime($request->get('date'));
    if (($waste_time / 60 % 60) < 10) {
        $minutes = '0'.($waste_time / 60 % 60);
    } else {
        $minutes = ($waste_time / 60 % 60);
    }
    if (($waste_time % 60) < 10) {
        $sec = '0'.($waste_time % 60);
    } else {
        $sec = ($waste_time % 60);
    }
    $result->time = (int) ($waste_time / 3600) . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $sec;

    /** Определяем количество правильных ответов */
    $exam = Exam::find($request->get('exam'));
    $questions = $exam->questions()->get();
    $result->question = count($questions);
    $right_count = 0;
    foreach ($questions as $question)
    {
        $right = true;
        if ($question->free) {
            $answer_right = $question->answerFree()->first();
            if ($request->has('free-answer-'.$answer_right->id)) {
                $answer = $request->get('free-answer-'.$answer_right->id);
                if (!strtoupper($answer) == strtoupper($answer_right->answer)) {
                    $right = false;
                }
            } else {
                $right = false;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($question->answers()->get() as $answer) {
                if ($right) {
                    if ($answer->right) {
                        if (!$request->has('answer-'.$answer->id)) {
                            $right = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($request->has('answer-'.$answer->id)) {
                            $right = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($right) {
            $right_count++;
        }

    }
    $result->right = $right_count;
    $result->save();

    /** Привязывает Результат к Тесту */
    $exam->results()->save($result);

    /** Привязывает Результат к Пользователю */
    $user = User::find($request->get('user'));
    $user->results()->save($result);

    /** Защитываем попытку */
    $user = \Auth::getUser();
    $futile = Futile::whereRaw('user_id = '.$user->id.' and exam_id = '.$exam->id)->first();
    $count = $futile->try_count;
    $count++;
    $futile->try_count = $count;
    $futile->save();
    $course = Course::find($request->get('course'));

    \Session::flash('my-messages', ['result' => 'Ваш результат: '.$result->right.' из '.$result->question]);            return \Redirect::route('pages.courses.show', $course->slug);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну просто сохраняйте в массив и на последней итерации заливайте , как то так :

```
function pushAnswer($questionId , $answerId , $insert = false){
    $_SESSION['question'][(int)$questionId] = (int)$answerId;
    if($insert){
        $data = serialize([ SID => $_SESSION['question'] ]);
        $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Собираем все ответы в сессию , на последнем шаге закрепляем за id сессии , сериализуем (ну если нужно просто слепок ответов сохранить)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу сохранения в массив, добавил код контроллера, что сохранять в массив и куда функцию описанную Вами выше подставить? Сам не могу разобраться уже довольно длительное время

Comment: ух , какой жирный контроллер . тут нужен рефакторинг  . Этот код лучше выделить в отдельный класс и раздробить на несколько целевых методов с учетом того что 1 метод должен выполнять 1 действие . Переменные с одинаковыми названиями подменяют друг друга , используйте только 1 присвоение . Вообще типичная лапша . Хотя бы разделите код на основные вехи и прокомментируйте каждую.

Comment: исправил и откомментировал код контроллера

Comment: Вероятней всего так : добавите метод `pushAnswer` в класс в котором находится `storeExam` , в цикле где вы перебираете ответы отправляйте данные `$this->pushAnswer($question->id , $answer->id);` в самом цикле нужно отследить последнюю итерацию и на ней выполнить `$this->pushAnswer($question->id , $answer->id , true);` . так же следует определить метод `$this->insert()` для сохранения исходных данных.

Comment: Не знаю где у вас хранится id самого вопроса , предположил что в $question->id , ну там уже отладитесь сами .

Comment: Не выходит у меня к сожалению быть может если у Вас будет время, Вы сможете посмотреть контроллер: https://bitbucket.org/averamtony/ucfps/src/dbe0178023d088a989e04e253c153838efea3e12/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default